# Connecting pjsua2 for android with asterisk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sip, pjsip

I have a server with asterisk 11.16.0 running. It does receive calls from web sipml5 client. Now I'm trying to make this server accept calls from an Android app.

Compiled  [PJSIP lib for android](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android) , genereted the PJSUA2 example project, imported the same to eclipse and runned it. And from that I'm stuck. My asterisk CLI doesn't print nothing when I try to connect, and the sample say "call disconnected: Unauthorized".

When the buddy is add with Subscribe presence box checked, the LOG also say "SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized".

Complete log of add buddy with subscribe presence box checked:

```
    06-29 16:30:59.914: I/System.out(28834): 16:30:59.914   pjsua_pres.c  Adding buddy: sip:003032@0.0.0.0
    06-29 16:30:59.914: I/System.out(28834): 16:30:59.914   pjsua_pres.c  .Buddy 0 added.
    06-29 16:30:59.914: I/System.out(28834): 16:30:59.914   pjsua_pres.c  .Buddy 0: unsubscribing presence..
    06-29 16:30:59.914: I/System.out(28834): 16:30:59.914   pjsua_pres.c  ..Buddy 0: updating presence..
    06-29 16:30:59.914: I/System.out(28834): 16:30:59.914   pjsua_pres.c  ...Buddy 0: subscribing presence,using account 0..
    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): 16:30:59.915   pjsua_core.c  ......TX 595 bytes Request msg SUBSCRIBE/cseq=19731 (tdta0xb9114598) to UDP 0.0.0.0:5060:
    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): SUBSCRIBE sip:003032@0.0.0.0 SIP/2.0

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 177.132.208.49:6000;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjegELMumdLOSusL9mQeOZRJqdIjlee2rH

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): Max-Forwards: 70

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): From: sip:localhost;tag=GTyVBRnFBBf3OuDUT6dsbUR1f-cxc3wN

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): To: sip:003032@0.0.0.0

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): Contact: <sip:177.132.208.49:6000;ob>;+sip.ice

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): Call-ID: 7ERxRcgeUPGvWZ07lsYfhS4b5ZBdJfIz

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): CSeq: 19731 SUBSCRIBE

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): Event: presence

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): Expires: 600

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): Accept: application/pidf+xml, application/xpidf+xml

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): Allow-Events: presence, message-summary, refer

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): User-Agent: Pjsua2 Android 2.4

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): Content-Length:  0

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): 

    06-29 16:30:59.915: I/System.out(28834): --end msg--
    06-29 16:30:59.927: I/System.out(28834): 16:30:59.926 evsub0xb90d9aa  ........Subscription state changed NULL --> SENT
    06-29 16:30:59.927: I/System.out(28834): 16:30:59.927   pjsua_pres.c  .........Presence subscription to sip:003032@0.0.0.0 is SENT
    06-29 16:30:59.927: I/System.out(28834): 16:30:59.927   pjsua_pres.c  Buddy 0: unsubscribing presence..
    06-29 16:30:59.927: I/System.out(28834): 16:30:59.927   pjsua_pres.c  .Buddy 0: updating presence..
    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:00.091   pjsua_core.c !.RX 571 bytes Response msg 401/SUBSCRIBE/cseq=19731 (rdata0xb8dd5a1c) from UDP 0.0.0.0:5060:
    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized

    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.25.7:6000;branch=z9hG4bKPjegELMumdLOSusL9mQeOZRJqdIjlee2rH;received=177.132.208.49;rport=6000

    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): From: sip:localhost;tag=GTyVBRnFBBf3OuDUT6dsbUR1f-cxc3wN

    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): To: sip:003032@0.0.0.0;tag=as4f8b5cb0

    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): Call-ID: 7ERxRcgeUPGvWZ07lsYfhS4b5ZBdJfIz

    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): CSeq: 19731 SUBSCRIBE

    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): Server: Asterisk PBX 11.16.0

    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE

    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): Supported: replaces, timer

    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="0.0.0.0", nonce="2bd940cd"

    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): Content-Length: 0

    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): 

    06-29 16:31:00.092: I/System.out(28834): --end msg--
    06-29 16:31:00.093: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:00.093 sip_auth_clien  ....Unable to set auth for tdta0xb9114598: can not find credential for 0.0.0.0/Digest
    06-29 16:31:00.094: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:00.093 evsub0xb90d9aa  ....Subscription state changed SENT --> TERMINATED
    06-29 16:31:00.095: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:00.094   pjsua_pres.c  .....Presence subscription to sip:003032@0.0.0.0 is TERMINATED
    06-29 16:31:00.096: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:00.095   pjsua_pres.c  ......Resubscribing buddy id 0 in 298427 ms (reason: Unauthorized)
    06-29 16:31:05.100: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:05.097 evsub0xb90d9aa  ...Subscription destroyed
```

And the log for when I try to make a call:

```
    06-29 16:31:17.206: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.206   pjsua_call.c !Making call with acc #0 to sip:003032@0.0.0.0
    06-29 16:31:17.206: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.206    pjsua_aud.c  .Set sound device: capture=-1, playback=-2
    06-29 16:31:17.206: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.206    pjsua_aud.c  ..Opening sound device PCM@16000/1/20ms
    06-29 16:31:17.206: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.206 android_jni_de  ...Creating Android JNI stream
    06-29 16:31:17.216: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.216 android_jni_de  ...Using audio input source : 7
    06-29 16:31:17.226: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.226 android_jni_de  ...Audio record initialized successfully.
    06-29 16:31:17.232: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.232 android_jni_de  ...Audio track initialized successfully.
    06-29 16:31:17.245: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.245   ec0xb914a1d0  ...AEC created, clock_rate=16000, channel=1, samples per frame=320, tail length=200 ms, latency=0 ms
    06-29 16:31:17.245: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.245 android_jni_de  ...Android JNI stream started
    06-29 16:31:17.246: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.246  pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: initializing media..
    06-29 16:31:17.246: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.246        icetp00  ..Creating ICE stream transport with 2 component(s)
    06-29 16:31:17.250: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.250 android_jni_de !Setting thread priority successful
    06-29 16:31:17.258: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.257 android_jni_de !Setting thread priority successful
    06-29 16:31:17.262: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.262        icetp00 !...Comp 1: srflx candidate starts Binding discovery
    06-29 16:31:17.284: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.283        icetp00  ...Comp 1: host candidate 192.168.25.7:46074 added
    06-29 16:31:17.284: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.284        icetp00  ...Comp 2: srflx candidate starts Binding discovery
    06-29 16:31:17.287: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.287        icetp00  ...Comp 2: host candidate 192.168.25.7:35330 added
    06-29 16:31:17.287: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.287        icetp00  ...ICE stream transport 0xb9144acc created
    06-29 16:31:17.287: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.287  pjsua_media.c  ..Media index 0 selected for audio call 0
    06-29 16:31:17.472: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.471 stuntp0xb91543 !.STUN mapped address found/changed: 177.132.208.49:46074
    06-29 16:31:17.476: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.474        icetp00  .Comp 1: Binding discovery complete, srflx address is 177.132.208.49:46074
    06-29 16:31:17.482: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.481 stuntp0xb90beb  .STUN mapped address found/changed: 177.132.208.49:35330
    06-29 16:31:17.490: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.488        icetp00  .Comp 2: Binding discovery complete, srflx address is 177.132.208.49:35330
    06-29 16:31:17.495: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.494        icetp00  ICE session created, comp_cnt=2, role is Controlling agent
    06-29 16:31:17.496: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.495        icetp00  ICE nomination type set to aggressive
    06-29 16:31:17.497: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.496        icetp00  Candidate 0 added: comp_id=1, type=srflx, foundation=Sc0a81907, addr=177.132.208.49:46074, base=192.168.25.7:46074, prio=0x6effffff (1862270975)
    06-29 16:31:17.498: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.497        icetp00  Candidate 1 added: comp_id=1, type=host, foundation=Hc0a81907, addr=192.168.25.7:46074, base=192.168.25.7:46074, prio=0x64ffffff (1694498815)
    06-29 16:31:17.500: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.499        icetp00  Candidate 2 added: comp_id=2, type=srflx, foundation=Sc0a81907, addr=177.132.208.49:35330, base=192.168.25.7:35330, prio=0x6efffffe (1862270974)
    06-29 16:31:17.501: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.500        icetp00  Candidate 3 added: comp_id=2, type=host, foundation=Hc0a81907, addr=192.168.25.7:35330, base=192.168.25.7:35330, prio=0x64fffffe (1694498814)
    06-29 16:31:17.507: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.506 tcpc0xb8fedf4c  ...TCP client transport created
    06-29 16:31:17.508: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.508 tcpc0xb8fedf4c  ...TCP transport 192.168.25.7:50535 is connecting to 0.0.0.0:5060...
    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.509   pjsua_core.c  ...TX 1491 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=1599 (tdta0xb9028db0) to TCP 0.0.0.0:5060:
    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): INVITE sip:003032@0.0.0.0 SIP/2.0

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 192.168.25.7:50535;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjy4Yv3yHJdognhMlKcSMv.YTVGPVZ75WR;alias

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): Max-Forwards: 70

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): From: sip:localhost;tag=Lsup6NqS0a9sXkWvAmx0JkNQAvagsfiD

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): To: sip:003032@0.0.0.0

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): Contact: <sip:177.132.208.49:6000;ob>;+sip.ice

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): Call-ID: XgfXiO2Crn.sfuvArPspUXmCqrSRDVv5

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): CSeq: 1599 INVITE

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): Session-Expires: 1800

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): Min-SE: 90

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): User-Agent: Pjsua2 Android 2.4

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): Content-Type: application/sdp

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): Content-Length:   863

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): 

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): v=0

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): o=- 3644595077 3644595077 IN IP4 177.132.208.49

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): s=pjmedia

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): b=AS:84

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): t=0 0

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): a=X-nat:8

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): m=audio 46074 RTP/AVP 98 97 99 104 3 0 8 9 96

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): c=IN IP4 177.132.208.49

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): b=TIAS:64000

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): a=rtcp:35330 IN IP4 177.132.208.49

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): a=sendrecv

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:99 speex/32000

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:104 iLBC/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): a=fmtp:104 mode=30

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.510: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.511: I/System.out(28834): a=fmtp:96 0-16

    06-29 16:31:17.511: I/System.out(28834): a=ice-ufrag:68e21bca

    06-29 16:31:17.511: I/System.out(28834): a=ice-pwd:63dec485

    06-29 16:31:17.511: I/System.out(28834): a=candidate:Sc0a81907 1 UDP 1862270975 177.132.208.49 46074 typ srflx raddr 192.168.25.7 rport 46074

    06-29 16:31:17.511: I/System.out(28834): a=candidate:Hc0a81907 1 UDP 1694498815 192.168.25.7 46074 typ host

    06-29 16:31:17.511: I/System.out(28834): a=candidate:Sc0a81907 2 UDP 1862270974 177.132.208.49 35330 typ srflx raddr 192.168.25.7 rport 35330

    06-29 16:31:17.511: I/System.out(28834): a=candidate:Hc0a81907 2 UDP 1694498814 192.168.25.7 35330 typ host

    06-29 16:31:17.511: I/System.out(28834): --end msg--
    06-29 16:31:17.673: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.672 tcpc0xb8fedf4c  TCP connect() error: Connection refused [code=120111]
    06-29 16:31:17.674: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.673  tsx0xb90c6f1c  Temporary failure in sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=1599 (tdta0xb9028db0), will try next server: Connection refused
    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.674   pjsua_core.c  TX 1486 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=1599 (tdta0xb9028db0) to UDP 0.0.0.0:5060:
    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): INVITE sip:003032@0.0.0.0 SIP/2.0

    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 177.132.208.49:6000;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjy4Yv3yHJdognhMlKcSMv.YTVGPVZ75WR

    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): Max-Forwards: 70

    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): From: sip:localhost;tag=Lsup6NqS0a9sXkWvAmx0JkNQAvagsfiD

    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): To: sip:003032@0.0.0.0

    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): Contact: <sip:177.132.208.49:6000;ob>;+sip.ice

    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): Call-ID: XgfXiO2Crn.sfuvArPspUXmCqrSRDVv5

    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): CSeq: 1599 INVITE

    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub

    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): Session-Expires: 1800

    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): Min-SE: 90

    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): User-Agent: Pjsua2 Android 2.4

    06-29 16:31:17.675: I/System.out(28834): Content-Type: application/sdp

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): Content-Length:   863

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): 

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): v=0

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): o=- 3644595077 3644595077 IN IP4 177.132.208.49

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): s=pjmedia

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): b=AS:84

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): t=0 0

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=X-nat:8

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): m=audio 46074 RTP/AVP 98 97 99 104 3 0 8 9 96

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): c=IN IP4 177.132.208.49

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): b=TIAS:64000

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=rtcp:35330 IN IP4 177.132.208.49

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=sendrecv

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:99 speex/32000

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:104 iLBC/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=fmtp:104 mode=30

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=fmtp:96 0-16

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=ice-ufrag:68e21bca

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=ice-pwd:63dec485

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=candidate:Sc0a81907 1 UDP 1862270975 177.132.208.49 46074 typ srflx raddr 192.168.25.7 rport 46074

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=candidate:Hc0a81907 1 UDP 1694498815 192.168.25.7 46074 typ host

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=candidate:Sc0a81907 2 UDP 1862270974 177.132.208.49 35330 typ srflx raddr 192.168.25.7 rport 35330

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): a=candidate:Hc0a81907 2 UDP 1694498814 192.168.25.7 35330 typ host

    06-29 16:31:17.676: I/System.out(28834): --end msg--
    06-29 16:31:17.679: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.678    pjsua_acc.c  Disconnected notification for transport tcpc0xb8fedf4c
    06-29 16:31:17.681: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.681 tcpc0xb8fedf4c  TCP transport destroyed with reason 120111: Connection refused
    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.930   pjsua_core.c  .RX 567 bytes Response msg 401/INVITE/cseq=1599 (rdata0xb8dd5a1c) from UDP 0.0.0.0:5060:
    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized

    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.25.7:6000;branch=z9hG4bKPjy4Yv3yHJdognhMlKcSMv.YTVGPVZ75WR;received=177.132.208.49;rport=6000

    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): From: sip:localhost;tag=Lsup6NqS0a9sXkWvAmx0JkNQAvagsfiD

    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): To: sip:003032@0.0.0.0;tag=as2dc039f2

    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): Call-ID: XgfXiO2Crn.sfuvArPspUXmCqrSRDVv5

    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): CSeq: 1599 INVITE

    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): Server: Asterisk PBX 11.16.0

    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE

    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): Supported: replaces, timer

    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="0.0.0.0", nonce="6ba922a0"

    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): Content-Length: 0

    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): 

    06-29 16:31:17.931: I/System.out(28834): --end msg--
    06-29 16:31:17.932: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.932   pjsua_core.c  ..TX 337 bytes Request msg ACK/cseq=1599 (tdta0xb8f8b3a0) to UDP 0.0.0.0:5060:
    06-29 16:31:17.932: I/System.out(28834): ACK sip:003032@0.0.0.0 SIP/2.0

    06-29 16:31:17.932: I/System.out(28834): Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 177.132.208.49:6000;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjy4Yv3yHJdognhMlKcSMv.YTVGPVZ75WR

    06-29 16:31:17.932: I/System.out(28834): Max-Forwards: 70

    06-29 16:31:17.932: I/System.out(28834): From: sip:localhost;tag=Lsup6NqS0a9sXkWvAmx0JkNQAvagsfiD

    06-29 16:31:17.932: I/System.out(28834): To: sip:003032@0.0.0.0;tag=as2dc039f2

    06-29 16:31:17.932: I/System.out(28834): Call-ID: XgfXiO2Crn.sfuvArPspUXmCqrSRDVv5

    06-29 16:31:17.932: I/System.out(28834): CSeq: 1599 ACK

    06-29 16:31:17.932: I/System.out(28834): Content-Length:  0

    06-29 16:31:17.933: I/System.out(28834): 

    06-29 16:31:17.933: I/System.out(28834): --end msg--
    06-29 16:31:17.934: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.933 sip_auth_clien  ....Unable to set auth for tdta0xb9028db0: can not find credential for 0.0.0.0/Digest
    06-29 16:31:17.940: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.939  pjsua_media.c  .....Call 0: deinitializing media..
    06-29 16:31:17.941: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.940  pjsua_media.c  ......Call 0: cleaning up provisional media, prov_med_cnt=1, med_cnt=0
    06-29 16:31:17.942: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.941        icetp00  ......Stopping ICE, reason=media stop requested
    06-29 16:31:17.942: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.942        icetp00  ......Destroying ICE session 0xb90d109c
    06-29 16:31:17.943: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.943        icetp00  .......ICE stream transport 0xb9144acc destroyed
    06-29 16:31:17.944: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:17.944  ice_session.c  .......ICE session 0xb90d109c destroyed
    06-29 16:31:18.945: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:18.944    pjsua_aud.c  Closing sound device after idle for 1 second(s)
    06-29 16:31:18.946: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:18.946    pjsua_aud.c  .Closing Android JNI sound playback device and Android JNI sound capture device
    06-29 16:31:18.947: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:18.946 android_jni_de  .Android JNI stream stopped
    06-29 16:31:18.948: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:18.947 android_jni_de  .Destroying Android JNI stream...
    06-29 16:31:18.994: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:18.994 android_jni_de  .Audio record released
    06-29 16:31:18.996: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:18.995 android_jni_de  .Audio track released
    06-29 16:31:18.996: I/System.out(28834): 16:31:18.996 android_jni_de  .Android JNI stream destroyed
```

The main problem is that I didnt understood how and where to set my settings, like server IP, ICE server, STUN, websocket_proxy_url. There is even some localhost in the logs, don't know why.

Tryed this  [JNI thing](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/page_pjsip_sample_simple_pjsuaua_c.htm), but didn't understood how to use that, so taking a look at the JNI now.

If anybody had used the JSIP for android and had some sucsses, any ideias or tutorial, not beeing the oficial, are welcome.

---

Working Sipml5 stack:

```
    sipStack = new SIPml.Stack({
            realm: sip_ip,
            impi: sip_id,
            impu: 'sip:'+sip_id+'@'+sip_ip+':'+sip_port,
            password: sip_pw,
            display_name: sip_id,
            websocket_proxy_url: 'ws://'+sip_ip+':'+sip_port+'/ws',
            ice_servers: "[{url:'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]",
            outbound_proxy_url: '',
            enable_rtcweb_breaker: false,
            events_listener: { events: '*', listener: sipEventsListener },
            enable_early_ims: false,
            enable_media_stream_cache: true,
            bandwidth: (window.localStorage ? tsk_string_to_object('') : null),
            video_size: (window.localStorage ? tsk_string_to_object('') : null),
            sip_headers: [
                    { name: 'User-Agent', value: 'IM-client/OMA1.0 sipML5-v1.0.0.0' },
                    { name: 'Organization', value: 'Tralala'}
            ]
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide credentials to your pjsua2 client for connecting to asterisk, probably the same that are used by sipml5 client

Comment: Just checked the documentation for account(http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/account.html) and Endpoint(http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/reference.html#project0group__PJSUA2__ACC_1ga635b99c7c941eaac95966887a39ae4d2) to see how to set credentials. Did not helped. Do you know where I can find an implementation of it?
obs: going to add my sipml5 stack to the question.

Comment: If you have compiled the client application for PJSUA, just look at the application help using the command line parameter --help. The important options are: --registrar=url     Set the URL of registrar server
  --realm=string      Set realm
  --username=string   Set authentication username
  --password=string